# App Crash When I try these code for Copy to clipboard in Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using below code in ViewPager Activity to perfom Copy to Clipboard button, working fine.

```
 mBtnCopy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                android.content.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.content.ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                android.content.ClipData clip = android.content.ClipData.newPlainText("Text Label", Html.fromHtml(mItemList.get(mViewPager.getCurrentItem())));
                clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.copy_to_clipboard), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

But, When I try this code in Recyclerview activity getting error "getCurrentItem".

below the code I am using for RecyclerActivity.

```
mBtnCopy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                android.content.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.content.ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                android.content.ClipData clip = android.content.ClipData.newPlainText("Text Label", Html.fromHtml(mItemList.get(mRecycler.getCurrentItem())));
                clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.copy_to_clipboard), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Include the stacktrace/crash log please.